# cq5 should be a synonym of aem

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I tried to apply the mapping to [aem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aem) myself but I am unable since

> Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators

However, CQ 5 is a marketing name which was changed to AEM and therefore not version specific. You will find answers related to AEM version 6 which are tagged [cq5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cq5) so that tag is not useful to distinguish between AEM versions.

- [Adobe AEM 6.1 Start up failed after Service Pack 2 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43765235/adobe-aem-6-1-start-up-failed-after-service-pack-2-upgrade)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43412232/aem-6-1-logging-out-on-creating-new-page
- [AEM 6.2: Using LinkTransformer - How is it triggered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43400274/aem-6-2-using-linktransformer-how-is-it-triggered)